# Equivalent code generated in return value optimization in c++

Tags: c++

I am not able to understand how is compiler able to optimize it under the covers. i.e, what is the equivalent code it generates?
There is an example of mentioned in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization which shows this code before optimization:

```
struct Data { char bytes[16]; };

Data * f(Data * __hiddenAddress)
{
    Data result = {};
    // copy result into hidden object
    *__hiddenAddress = result;
    return __hiddenAddress;
}

int main()
{
    Data __hidden; // create hidden object
    Data d = *f(&__hidden); // copy the result into d
}
```

It does not say the equivalent code ofter optimization

Answer (score 3):

Ok, the page has proven to be less than clear, as I've misread it on my first scan (oops). The following is listed as **before optimization**:

```
struct Data { char bytes[16]; };
Data f()
{
  Data result = {};
  // generate result
  return result;
}

int main()
{
  Data d = f();
}
```

The code *you listed* was the *non-optimzed* pseudo version as a compiler might interpret that, complete with temporary and copy construction. What it shows, is how a compiler will translate into procedural code a function that returns a value (return value passing mechanism).

After that, the code after optimization is listed none-the-less:

```
struct Data { char bytes[16]; };

void f(Data * p)
{
  // generate result directly in *p
}

int main()
{
  Data d;
  f(&d);
}
```

I.e.: the compiler is allowed to work on the destination of the return value directly, bypassing the construction/destruction/copy of a temporary instance within the function body.

Comment: No, that's not right.  This is the code as written.  The Questioners code is the code without the optimization (but other things done to it)

Comment: it says "which causes the Data object to be copied twice." after the code

Comment: You might want to read the wikipedia article again. The OPs code fragment is what might be genereated **without** optimization. However there is the optimized variant shown below.

Comment: Obviously, *his* copy of wikipedia is not the same as *ours*.

Comment: @lou: you're right. I was reading what I expected too read and not really looking too well. If you can add a few lines of explanation to your answer, I will delete this one.

Comment: Ok, I have opted to just fix my answer. Everyone thanks for putting up with my hasty error; it should be better now.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct Data { char bytes[16]; };

void f(Data * useThisInsteadOfReturning)
{ 
   // update *useThisInsteadOfReturning directly
}

int main()
{
  Data d;
  f(&d); // use d in the function
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The optimized code is shown below the one you mentioned. To quote from the wikipedia site:

```
struct Data { char bytes[16]; };

void f(Data * p)
{
   // generate result directly in *p
}

int main()
{
   Data d;
   f(&d);
}
```

So the compiler can figure out that it has reserved memory to hold the return value from the function and it treats it as if a pointer to that memory had been passed as parameter and it writes directly into it instead of creating another temp object inside the function and then copying the memory around.

Comment: Just note that the compiler would not use the default constructor to build the return value and then assign to it.  It would just allocate the memory and then construct the object in place where the return statement lies.